# How to create a timer function that can be called multiple times before it ends?

Tags: python, time, timer

I want to set multiple timers (same function) at the same time, but with different ending times. Coding in python 3.
My code currently is:

```
import time
def timer(t):
  start = time.time()
  stop = False
  while not stop:
    if time.time()> start+t:
      print("I'm done counting to %d" % t)
      stop = True

timer(4)
timer(1)
timer(5)
```

Now I would like it would first print 1, then 4 and finally 5, but instead it runs completely timer(4) and only after that it continues to the next timer.
I've heard a bit about multi-threading, but couldn't find a good example how to implement it in my code.
Eventually, I would also like to add an option to delay the start of the timer with n seconds.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just about timers, you can use directly timers, without more complicated multi-threading:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#timer-objects

```
import threading

def hello():
    print("hello, world")

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()  # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

Try this one: (Tested on my machine, Python 3.8.2)

```
from threading import Timer

def hello(t):
    print("Counted to", t)

t1 = Timer(4, hello, [4])
t1.start()
t2 = Timer(1, hello, [1])
t2.start()
t3 = Timer(3, hello, [3])
t3.start()
```

In order to delay the start, add other timers which call a function that does nothing.

These type of timers are called only once though at the ending time.